# EF Many-to-Many removal not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, many-to-many

I've checked in at least 20 different places about how to delete a many-to-many registry using Entity Framework, and my code seems to be working according to almost all solutions I found. Unfortunately, I can't delete the relationship, no matter what. Here's the code:

```
using (var db = new Context())
{                
    var project = db.Projects.Single(p => p.Id == "myId");

    foreach (var toRemove in project.Orders.Where(o =>
                                     ordersToRemove.Select(otr => otr.Id).Contains(o.Id)).ToList())
    {
         project.Orders.Remove(toRemove);

    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I also tried to force the removal inside the "foreach", getting the order from "db" and removing the Project relationship from it, just to test, but it was useless.

**As a matter of information, I've debugged it and my Orders collection inside project had the Orders removed correctly right before "SaveChanges".**

In the same code I have a very similar flow to add orders to Project and it works fine.

I did the mapping in Context manually, like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Orders)
            .WithMany(o => o.Projects)
            .Map(pc =>
            {
                pc.MapLeftKey("ProjectId");
                pc.MapRightKey("OrderId");
                pc.ToTable("Projects_Orders");
            });
```

I believe it's something silly that I can't figure out, so because of it I ask your help. Sorry if it's a duplicated question, but like I said before, I found a lot of answers that the code is pretty the same as mine.

**UPDATED:** I found out someone which had the same issue as me ([here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b3998a0-6b6a-40b9-8c4f-e8e04f39895b/remove-with-manytomany-relationship-doesnt-work-in-entity-framework-41?forum=adodotnetentityframework)), and I tried to use the marked solution, but didn't work. I also tried to clear all collection, then save, and then add again the orders that should remain, and didn't work either. Another solution was to create an entity for the related table (something like ProjectOrder), but I thought it would be too damn ugly.

In the end, I used "executesqlcommand" - **and I'm not proud of it**. I just couldn't waste more time in it, unfortunately.

Comment: Why is there a NOT (!) in the ordersToRemove subselect? and what is ordersToRemove?

Comment: Mistyped, sorry. Already corrected.
ordersToRemove is a List<Order> object.
As a matter of information, I've debugged it and my Orders collection inside project had the Orders removed correctly right before "SaveChanges".

Comment: Are you getting any specific exception?

Comment: Are you checking the right database? (Sorry for asking, but I've seen it happen too often -- I mean, checking another instance of the database). Also, did you check the SQL that's executed by `SaveChanges`?

Comment: @Vinod, there's no exception. It runs fine.

Comment: @GertArnold, I have only one database, and the Trace gives me no SQL when I run SaveChanges =/

Comment: @thiagoprzy In similar situations, I've had to double-check that the Orders property is actually being populated with the Project's Orders - you can't delete/remove what you don't have in memory. Depending on the version of EF you're using, it might be worth updating the code to pull the entity from the database using `db.Projects.Include(p => p.Orders).Single(p => p.Id == "myId");` That said, this may not fix anything; but I think it's worth a check.

Comment: @janamargaret, thanks for your answer, but I've already tried this before with no success, unfortunately =/

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**: Previous answer was reflecting how to delete One-Many, here is an updated sample that I tried and I am able to delete Many-To-Many relationship without any issues. Please ignore the naming convention as I put this together real quick for testing purpose.

ORDER Entity

```
namespace TestEF6.Data
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("ORDER")]
    public partial class ORDER
    {
        public ORDER()
        {
            PROJECTS = new HashSet<PROJECT>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string NAME { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PROJECT> PROJECTS { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PROJECT entity

```
namespace TestEF6.Data
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("PROJECT")]
    public partial class PROJECT
    {
        public PROJECT()
        {
            ORDERS = new HashSet<ORDER>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string NAME { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ORDER> ORDERS { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Context class

```
namespace TestEF6.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    public partial class ProjectManagerContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjectManagerContext()
            : base("name=ProjectManager")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ORDER> ORDERs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PROJECT> PROJECTs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

            modelBuilder.Entity<PROJECT>()
            .HasMany(p => p.ORDERS)
            .WithMany(o => o.PROJECTS)
            .Map(pc =>
            {
                pc.MapLeftKey("PROJECT_ID");
                pc.MapRightKey("ORDER_ID");
                pc.ToTable("PROJECT_ORDER");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

UNIT TESTS

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TestEF6.Data.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ProjectOrderTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Can_Remove_Projects_And_Orders_Relation()
        {
            using (var db = new ProjectManagerContext())
            {
                var proj1 = db.PROJECTs.Single(p => p.NAME == "TEST PROJ 1");

                Debug.WriteLine($"Num of proj1 orders = [{proj1.ORDERS.Count}]");
                foreach (var order in proj1.ORDERS.ToList())
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Removed proj order = [{proj1.NAME}] [{order.NAME}]");
                    proj1.ORDERS.Remove(order);

                }

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void Can_Add_Projects_And_Orders()
        {
            using (var db = new ProjectManagerContext())
            {
                var proj1 = new PROJECT { NAME = "TEST PROJ 1" };
                var proj2 = new PROJECT { NAME = "TEST PROJ 2" };
                var proj3 = new PROJECT { NAME = "TEST PROJ 3" };
                db.PROJECTs.Add(proj1);
                db.PROJECTs.Add(proj2);
                db.PROJECTs.Add(proj3);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var order1 = new ORDER { NAME = "ORDER 1" };
                var order2 = new ORDER { NAME = "ORDER 2" };

                db.ORDERs.Add(order1);
                db.ORDERs.Add(order2);
                db.SaveChanges();

                proj1.ORDERS.Add(order1);
                proj1.ORDERS.Add(order2);
                proj2.ORDERS.Add(order2);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Here is config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjectManager" connectionString="data source=MYTESTSQL2014;initial catalog=ProjectManagerDb;user id=test_user;password=test$pwd!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Here is how the table structure in SQL server is defined and the join table foreign key columns are set to Allow nulls.

[image: Project Order Relationship diagram]

Test Results

[image]

There were 3 rows in PROJECT_ORDER table before deletion

[image]

There is just one row after the delete

[image]

Comment: Hello, Vinod. 
This solution only solves to a one-to-many relationship, as the URL title says. My issue is related to a many-to-many relationship. In other words, I don't want to delete de order, because it can be related to another project. I wanto to delete the relationship between project and order.

Comment: Sorry, I previously misunderstood your question. What you have should work. I have a similar use case and it works fine. How sure you are that the execution is reaching project.Orders.Remove(toRemove); line?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. About your question: 100% sure, since I've debugged it and my Orders collection inside project had the Orders removed correctly right before "SaveChanges".
My code is quite the same as yours, including the "null" in table columns, so It's really a mistery why it's not working. More information in the "updated" session in my post.

Comment: Which version of EF are you using and which version of .NET Framework?

Comment: EF 6 (runtime version v4.0.30319), .NET 4.5

Comment: Which specific version of EF6 (6.0.0 or 6.1.0 or 6.1.3 etc?) How about .NET framework (just .net 4.5 or .net 4.5.1 or .net 5.1.2)?

Comment: 4.5 only, and EF 6.0.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135703/discussion-between-vinod-and-thiagoprzy).